# Move set of open Safari windows/tabs to another Mac

Tags: macos, safari, bookmarks, url

I have a bunch of windows & tabs open in Safari. I want to view all the same windows and tabs on another Mac.

☞ Is there a set of URLs or bookmarks somewhere used by Safari to remember open windows/tabs between sessions? Might I be able to grab a copy of those URLs or bookmarks to put on a thumb drive?

I know Macs and iPads can hand off the top currently viewed Safari window between each other. But I want to move all of a few dozen open windows & tabs.

Comment: Basil Bourque, In case you've not seen my update answer, I have since tested it and it works as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

> ☞ Is there a set of URLs or bookmarks somewhere used by Safari to remember open windows/tabs between sessions?

In **macOS Catalina** the **~/Library/Safari/LastSession.plist** *file* contains a list of all open *windows* and their *tabs*.

Note that while it's called **LastSession.plist**, nonetheless, it does contain the current *windows* and their *tabs*.

You can try copying this file to the same location on the other **Mac** and see if it gives you what you want. In case it's not obvious, **Safari** needs to be closed when replacing this *file*.

I tested copying the **LastSession.plist** *file* from **macOS Catalina** to **macOS Big Sur** and it worked by opening **Safari** and selecting **Reopen All Windows from Last Session** from the **History** *menu*.

<sub>I'm currently using **Safari** version 14.0.3 (15610.4.3.1.6, 15610) on **macOS Catalina** and **Safari** version 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4) on **macOS Big Sur**.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Tab groups in Safari 15 synchronise over iCloud. You can switch to a tab group from another Mac and all your tabs will be opened. Opening or closing a tab in a tab group on one Mac will perform the same action on another Mac.

You can make a new tab group from all your current tabs from the tab group menu, which you can then open on another Mac to transfer/synchronise your current tabs.

[image]